# How to convert DOMNodeList object into array

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     $dom->load('file.xml');
     $names = $dom->getElementsByTagName('name');
```

Now, `$names` is DOMNodeList object, I need to convert this object into an array,

```
     $names = (array)$names;
     var_dump($names);  // empty array
```

The above code does not work and returns an empty array, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>Why doesn't [(array)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) work? Because a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object has only one property, [length](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length), and it's of integer type:</del>

> <del>If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: **integer properties are
>   unaccessible**; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.</del>

Since a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) implements the [Traversable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface, it's fairly easy to create the array yourself:

```
$array = array();
foreach($names as $node){
    $array[] = $node;
}
```

---

**Edit:** I've removed the initial explanation because it doesn't apply here. What the manual means is that properties with numeric names are passed to the array but cannot be read:

```
<?php

class Foo{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->{123} = 456;
    }
}

$array = (array)new Foo;
var_dump($array);
var_dump($array['123']);
```

```
array(1) {
  ["123"]=>
  int(456)
}

Notice: Undefined offset: 123 in D:\tmp\borrame.php on line 11
NULL
```

The explanation is probably more on the line that `DOMNodeList` is not a user object created with PHP code but a builtin object defined in C, so different rules apply.

Answer (score 85):

Use iterator_to_array() to convert a DomNodeList to an Array

```
$document = new DomDocument();
$document->load('test.xrds');
$nodeList = $document->getElementsByTagName('Type');
$array = iterator_to_array($nodeList);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It works and is very simple.

Comment: Agreed. This is best.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to iterator_to_array() must implement interface Traversable, instance of DOMNodeList given`

Comment: FWIW, as of the documentation I'm reading (5.6.35), `DOMNodeList` implements `Traversable`. The change log in the docs is silent on when this changed. I also haven't tried this particular solution and there may be other bugs in play.

Answer (score 5):

Just iterate trough the elements and put them into an array:

```
$names_array = array();
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $names_array[] = $name; // this is a DOMNode instance
    // you might want to have the textContent of them like this
    $names_array[] = $name->textContent;
}
```

This way they still will be DOMNode instances, you might want to get their `textContent` property.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the actual values and not to create an array of DOM nodes:

```
foreach($nodelist as $node) {
    $values[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('file.xml');
$names = $dom->getElementsByTagName('name');
$headlines = array();

foreach($names as $name) {
    $headline = array();
    if($name->childNodes->length) {
        foreach($name->childNodes as $i) {
            $headline[$i->nodeName] = $i->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    $headlines[] = $headline;
}
```