# Extract pattern from xml file using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, find, pattern-matching

I have a remote XML file. I need to read, find some values an save them in an array.

I've got load the file with (no problem with this):

```
$xml_external_path = 'http://example.com/my-file.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($xml_external_path);
```

In this file there are many instances of:

```
<unico>4241</unico>
<unico>234</unico>
<unico>534534</unico>
<unico>2345334</unico>
```

I need to extract just the number of these strings and save them in a array. I guess I need to use a pattern like:

```
$pattern = '/<unico>(.*?)<\/unico>/';
```

But I'm not sure what to do next. Keep in mind that it is an .xml file.

Result should be a populated array like this:

```
$my_array = array (4241, 234, 534534,2345334);
```

Comment: And what language are you programming in? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: A good advice: *Keep in mind that it is a .xml file.* What tools do we use to handle data in XML? XML parser, I guess.

Comment: I just updated my question: PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this, it basically just loops through each line of the file and finds whatever is between the XML `<unico>` tags.

```
<?php

$file = "./your.xml";
$pattern = '/<unico>(.*?)<\/unico>/';
$allVars = array();

$currentFile = fopen($file, "r");
if ($currentFile) {
    // Read through file
    while (!feof($currentFile)) {
        $m_sLine = fgets($currentFile);
        // Check for sitename validity
        if (preg_match($pattern, $m_sLine) == true) {
            $curVar = explode("<unico>", $m_sLine);
            $curVar = explode("</unico>", $curVar[1]);
            $allVars[] = $curVar[0];
        }
    }
}
fclose($currentFile);
print_r($allVars);
```

Is this sort of what you want? :)

Comment: I get the array but with no values in it.

Comment: Odd, it works fine for me. [image](https://pximg.xyz/images/pxgamer/e960fec187faaa0bd9f1baf2e96ef572.png)

Could you provide the content of the XML file?

Comment: I can't do that with the real xml. I will create a sample to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can better use XPath to read through an XML file. XPath is a variant of DOMDocument focused on reading and editing XML files. You can query an XPath variable using patterns, which is based on the simple Unix path syntax. So `//` means anywhere and `./` means relative to selected node. `XPath->query()` will return a [DOMNodelist](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) with all the nodes according to the pattern. The following code will do what you want:

```
$xmlFile = "
<unico>4241</unico>
<unico>234</unico>
<unico>534534</unico>
<unico>2345334</unico>";

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

// This code returns a DOMNodeList of all nodes with the unico tags in the file.
$unicos = $xpath->query("//unico");

//This returns an integer of how many nodes were found that matched the pattern
echo $unicos->length;
```

You can find more info on XPath and its syntax here: [XPath on Wikipedia#syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Abbreviated_syntax)

DOMNodeList implements Traversable, so you can use foreach() to traverse it. If you really want a flat array you can simply convert is using simple code like in [question #15807314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807314/how-to-convert-domnodelist-object-into-array):

```
$unicosArr = array();
foreach($unicos as $node){
    $unicosArr[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using preg_match_all:

```
<?php
$xml = '<unico>4241</unico>
<unico>234</unico>
<unico>534534</unico>
<unico>2345334</unico>';

$pattern = '/<unico>(.*?)<\/unico>/';

preg_match_all($pattern,$xml,$result);
print_r($result[0]);
```

Comment: Pretty sure `preg_match_all()` won't work as there are lines with things before and after the unico tags.

Comment: Don't know what exactly you mean but the regex pattern is supposed to extract what inside the tags