# How can I get my XML Link List automatically sorted?

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I have a well working livesearch which takes the results from my XML List. But I need to add many links to it and I wonder if there is a way to automatically sort them alphabetically to save time. I need them sorted from A to Z because the results should not be in a random order.

Is there a way to maybe add them into a php page or something and display them sorted in my XML file? Or maybe work with classes?

```
<pages>
<link>
<title>Volvo</title>
<url>https://www.example.com</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>Audi</title>
<url>https://www.example.com</url>
</link>
<link>
<title>Mercedes</title>
<url>https://www.example.com</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

This is the PHP Code:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (strpos(strtolower($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue), strtolower($q)) === 0) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Do you need them to be ordered inside the actual XML file - or do you just want to present the livesearch results in alphabetical order? If the latter, then it would probably be a lot easier to sort only the filtered results at that point, assuming they will probably be contained in an array structure at this point already?

Comment: I need only to present them in the livesearch in alphabetical order ... I thought I have to make that in my XML file. What code is important? PHP?

Comment: Okay, so here all output is generated in HTML form inside the loop already, and concatened into one single variable $hint - that is not very suitable for sorting afterwards. You could only add the nodeValues to an array there instead, sort that after the loop, and then create the output from that - or you sort your input data already, in that case you would first of all need to transform the DOMNodeList that getElementsByTagName returned, into an array (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807314/how-to-convert-domnodelist-object-into-array)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but that looks very complicated to me since im not a pro in this. i thought something like getElementsByClassName instead of ($x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');) and sort them through php maybe and display the results in my xml file? totally wrong thought?

Comment: Switching out one method of selecting the relevant nodes from the XML, for another, won’t change much about this.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM methods return node lists, more specific a \DOMNodeList object. This object implements the `Traversable` interface (The parent interface for Iterators). You can use `iterator_to_array()` to convert the node list into an array and `usort()` to sort that array.

To filter the link nodes directly you can use an Xpath expression that calls back into PHP.

```
// bootstrap the link xml
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);

// use ext/intl transliterator to create a lowercase ascii string
function normalize(string $string) {
    return \Transliterator::create('Any-Lower; Latin-ASCII')->transliterate($string);
}

// register the "normalize" function 
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions(['normalize']);

// build an expression that filters the nodes using a search string
$searchFor = 'd';
$expression = '//link[
    contains(php:function("normalize", string(title)), "'.$searchFor.'")
]';
// map data into a nested array
$links = array_map(
    function(\DOMNode $node) use ($xpath) {
        return [ 
            'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node),
            'url' => $xpath->evaluate('string(url)', $node)
        ];
    },
    iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate($expression))
);

// create a locale specific string collator
$collator = new Collator('en_US');
// sort the link data array
usort(
    $links,    
    function(array $a, array $b) use ($collator) {
        return $collator->compare($a['title'], $b['title']);
    }
);

var_dump($links);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Audi"
    ["url"]=>
    string(23) "https://www.example.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Mercedes"
    ["url"]=>
    string(23) "https://www.example.com"
  }
}
```

DOM can be used to create the HTML output also. This allows the DOM serializer to take care of special characters.

```
// a target document for the HTML output
$target = new DOMDocument();
// fragments are node lists that can be treated as a single node
$targetFragment = $target->createDocumentFragment();

foreach($links as $link) {
    // if the fragment contains nodes add a break
    if ($targetFragment->hasChildNodes()) {
        $targetFragment->appendChild($target->createElement('br'));
    }
    
    // create and append "a" element node
    $targetFragment->appendChild(
        $a = $target->createElement('a')
    );
    $a->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    $a->setAttribute('href', $link['url']);
    $a->textContent = $link['title'];
}
// save the fragment as HTML
echo $target->saveHTML($targetFragment);
```

Output:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com">Audi</a><br><a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com">Mercedes</a>
```

Comment: thank you very much. just one thing, how can I use this with my files? I mean where I have to insert the code? What type of files are these?

Comment: Well, I used `$source->loadXml(getXML());` in the snippet to load the data from a function (making the snippet self contained). `$source->load($xmlFileName);` would load a file.